# Excel: Count cells in range if they are equal to cell above

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm just wanting to have a formula to count the amount of cells from E4:X4 if the number in each cell in that range is equal to the number in the cell directly above it. I was trying doing a COUNTIF with an INDIRECT ADDRESS for the cells above but didn't get anything so I was probably doing it quite wrong. 
Just to be very clear for example if in that range cell E4 is 5 and above it (E3) is also 5 then to count it, and not count it if it isn't. Same for every cell down to X4.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Sumproduct for that. In the screenshot, the formula in cell I2 is

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(A1:G1=A2:G2))
```

[image]

To count only non-empty cells, you can change the formula to

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(A1:G1=A2:G2),--(A2:G2<>""))
```

[image]

Comment: Hi thanks for that. Works great. Just a couple other things hopefully you can answer. I got it to =SUMPRODUCT(--(E4:X4=E3:X3-1)) to count if the number was 1 less, but I also want another one to only count if E4:X4 were 3 less or more than E3:X3? And I forgot to ask how I can have the function only use it if there is data in E4:X4. E3:X3 would always have data but only compare if E4:X4 had data in it. Thank you.

Comment: I figured out the +-3 bit but I still don't know how to only have it work if the cells in range are empty. I would guess some kind of IF statement but not sure. This is what I came up with for the other issue. I also wanted a gap between them so this is what I got: 
=SUMPRODUCT(--(E4:M4<E3:M3-2)--(P4:X4<P3:X3-2))